# symbols in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In mathematics, we know that if we want to introduce a new symbol, we must check two things.

1. The symbol names at least one object.  (For existence)
2. The symbol does not name more than one object.  (For uniqueness)

In set theory, we may form sets like $\{2,3,4,5\}$ and $\{2,4,5,6\}$. Now, the symbol $\{2,3,4,5\}$ names a set whose elements are exactly $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$. Because $\{2,3,4,5\}$ is symbol for  a certain set , ie, a set  whose elements are exactly 2,3,4,5, we shall check two things:
I : Is there a set whose elements are exactly 2 , 3, 4 , 5?
II : Is  such set unique ?
Suppose there exists a set whose elements are exactly $a_{1} ,a_{2} , ... a_{n}$ .
So we use the symbol  $\{a_{1},a_{2},a_{3} , .... a_{n} \}$ to denote a set   whose elements are exactly $a_{1} ,a_{2} , ... a_{n}$ .
Does the symbol $\{a_{1},a_{2},a_{3} , .... a_{n} \}$ name only one object ?

My first question is that whenever I write symbol $\{c_{1},c_{2} , .... c_{n}\}$ , is the symbol well-defined ? (Suppose there exists a set whose elements are exactly $c_{1} ,c_{2} ... c_{n}$ )
My second question is that is the first question meaningless ?
My third question is that:
if the first question is meaningless, then please tell me why .
if the first question is meaningful  and  you answer "yes" then  please tell me why  ?
if the first question is meaningful  and  you answer "no" then  please tell me why  ?
Thanks.

Comment: First question: "is the symbol $\{ 2,3,4,5 \}$ well-defined ?" Yes; see [Set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation): the syntax is $\{x \mid \Phi (x) \}$ where $\Phi (x)$ is a formula of the langugae with variable $x$ free. Thus, your example can be rewritten as follows: $\{ x \mid x=2 \lor x=3 \lor x=4 \lor x=5 \}$

Comment: 2nd and 3rd questions: see answer to 1st one.