# A question for list elements of nonempty finite set .

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am studying set theory but I have a question.
If we have a finite nonempty set. Here , we let A denotes it, but I do not know what its elements exactly are.

May I write ?

> Let $c_{1},c_{2} ,\dots, c_{n} ∈ S$ and  $A= \{ c_{1},c_{2}, \dots,  c_{n} \}$ for some $n ∈ \mathbb N$.

Is this a way to list all the elements of set A ?

My question is that if I want to list all the elements of a finite set,
do I know what its elements exactly are or I do not need to know what its elements exactly are and  just use the above-listed way then I can list all the elements of A .

Thanks  .

Comment: Not very clear... The [Set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate) is: $S = \{ x \mid \Phi(x) \}$ where $\Phi(x)$ is a formula "specifying" a property. Regarding e.g. $\mathbb N$, we can write $\Phi(x) := x=1 \lor x=2$ and thus $S= \{ 1,2 \}$ or we may use a formula like $\Phi(x) := 0 < x < 3$ in which case $S= \{ 1,2 \}$.

Comment: In conclusion, a "list" is... a list, and thus it will contain all elements, but you can use a formula that "describes" the list without necessarily list all its elements.

Comment: Same as your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326566/symbols-in-set-theory)